# Loop to reload data from each store in ExtJS Sencha

Tags: for-loop, extjs, sencha-touch

I have 3 or more stores (A,B,C) which I want to reload with passed parameters. Can I use a loop to reload all of them?

```
 onClickRefreshButton: function() {       
    Ext.getStore('A').reload({
        params: {
            FirstParameter: 123,
            SecondParameter:456,
            ThirdParameter: 789,
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a fiddle that does what you need:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cbh

In my previous solution, I forgot to specify the scope:

```
 myArrayStores.forEach(st => { st.reload(); }, this);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please, mark the answer as the correct answer if it is valid. :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Why not?

myArrayStores.forEach(st => { st.reload(); });

Comment: Thank you @Cesar but I get TypeError: st.reload is not a function
    `onClickRefreshButton: function() {       
        var myArrayStores =  ['A', 'B', 'C'];        
        myArrayStores.forEach((st) => {
                st.reload({
                params: {
                      FirstParameter: 123,
                      SecondParameter:456,
                      ThirdParameter: 789,
                }
            });
        });`